# Can't access pods behind service

Tags: kubernetes, weave

I'm attempting to access a WebSphere App Server I have running on Kubernetes, and I can't seem to be able to connect properly. I have a pod running behind a service that should connect it's admin console port to an external NodePort. Problem is it resets the connection every time I try. I had the same issue with an ssh port for another pod, but that was fixed when I fixed a Weave networking error. At this point, I can't tell if it's a Kubernetes or Weave error, or something else all together. Any help would be appreciated.

I'm running KubeV1.1.0 off the release-1.1 branch, Mesos 0.24.0, and Weave 1.0.1. My next step is to try a different version of K8s.

Answer (score 2):

The Kubernetes release-1.1 branch was cut before the master branch started passing conformance tests on Mesos. A lot of work has been done since then to make Kubernetes on Mesos more usable. Not all of those changes/fixes have been backported/cherry-picked to fix the v1.1 release branch. It's probably a better idea to try using the code from master branch for the time being, at least while the kubernetes-mesos integration is in alpha. We hope future point releases will be more stable.

(I work on the Kubernetes-Mesos team at Mesosphere.)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I rebuilt using the latest pull from master but that actually seemed to regress. There may be something wrong with the node on which the services gets placed. I'm going to investigate this a bit more.

Comment: Just checking back in. I tried to update a few things, moving from Mesos 0.24.0 to 0.24.1, and several different versions of Kubernetes, and now my Mesos cluster won't seem to recognize k8s as a framework. Not really sure what happened here.